# Cannot deploy Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have referred to several different sources in order to try to push Heroku..

the error code I'm getting is:

```
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.

  Failed to install gems via Bundler.

  Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

I've tried several Gemfile configurations but this is what I currently have:

```
group :production, :staging do
  gem "pg"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3-ruby", "~> 1.3.0", :require => "sqlite3"
end
```

I've also tried different bundles after.. bundle, bundle install, bundle install --without development

I keep getting the same error.

Please help

Thank you

ps: Please note, I'm new with a lot of this.. So please be as specific as possible.

Thanks again

Comment: That technically should work. Are you sure you are pushing the right branch to heroku? Are did you update and commit your Gemfile and run bundle install?

Comment: It's a bad idea to run sqlite locally and postgres in production. Use the same database everywhere.

Comment: @LeoCorrea currently I only have one branch. should I have a different one? Also I've tried bundle, bundle install bundle install --without development

Comment: not sure what changed, but it's working now. Thanks everyone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387869/heroku-deploy-problems-still

answer found here..

Answer (score 0):

try (on fedora) or equivalent, and then either install this gem alone or restart the bundle.

```
yum install sqlite-devel
```