# Heroku deploy problems.. still

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, heroku

Yesterday I had asked a question about pushing Heroku.. it wasn't working, and then suddenly started working. I changed nothing. Now on a new app, I'm having the exact same problem. I've decided to include my entire Gemfile in hopes that I can continue on without this incredible frustration

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

group :production, :staging do
  gem "pg"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3-ruby", "~> 1.3.0", :require => "sqlite3"
end

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.3'
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

 gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

After updating the gem file I ran:

```
$bundle install
$git add Gemfile
$git add Gemfile.lock
$git git commit -m "message"
$git push heroku master
```

Still I'm getting this error though

```
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:warm-dusk-1436.git
  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:warm-dusk-1436.git'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's having trouble installing the `sqlite3` gem, which is specified in your Gemfile to be installed in *all* environments, even though Heroku won't use it.

Try moving `gem 'sqlite3'` to the development group so that your production environment doesn't attempt to install it.

Comment: Also, make sure your in 'master' branch in your local machine.